# Scope of Google Map variable and calling method

Tags: javascript, google-maps, scope

I'm playing with the Google Maps API to familiarise myself with JavaScript. I'm a terrible programmer, so please forgive me.

I'm not quite sure why the following code doesn't work, you can check a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/m9QLx/

```
var map;

function initialize() {

var myOptions = {
      center : new google.maps.LatLng(34.053228, -118.259583),
      zoom   : 11,
      zoomControl: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    },

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(37.4569, -122.1569));
```

Everything works fine but I'm not sure why the `panTo` method doesn't work, as far as I can work out, declaring var map outside of all functions makes it global, I then set map in the `initialize()` function but outside of this `initialize()` function the `panTo` method doesn't work, map appears to be undefined.

I'm sure I'm making a rookie mistake but I can't find an answer (I'm sure I'm Googling the wrong thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the map.panTo method before the map is initialized.

This causes the initialize function to run when the page fires its "load" event (the complete DOM/page has been rendered):

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

This executes immediately, before the "load" event fires and the map variable is initialized:

```
map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(37.4569, -122.1569));
```

So it doesn't do anything.  You should move it into your initialize function after the map is initialized.

```
var map;

function initialize() {

var myOptions = {
      center : new google.maps.LatLng(34.053228, -118.259583),
      zoom   : 11,
      zoomControl: true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(37.4569, -122.1569));    
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much. If I may be so bold, with the following updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m9QLx/3/ - should I be doing something different with the function called when the button is clicked on? I'm not sure where the panTo method should be for this to work?

Comment: Because of the comma after the myOptions declaration.  Should be a semi-colon. http://jsfiddle.net/m9QLx/5/

Comment: Man I am quite silly. Thanks so much for your help geocodezip